# Completing the Square (Bivariate)

Tags: linear-algebra, completing-the-square

I am running a bivariate regression with the formula
$$\hat{Z} = b_0+b_1X+b_2Y+b_3X^2+b_4Y^2+b_5XY$$
I'm easily able to obtain the 6 coefficients this way. However, I want to reparameterize the formula as 
$$\hat{Z} = \alpha + \dfrac 1 {σ_{xx} σ_{zz}-σ_{xz}^2} \Big[σ_{zz}(X-μ_x)^2-2σ_{xz}(X-μ_x)(Z-μ_z)+σ_{xx}(Z-μ_z)^2\Big]$$
Sadly, I'm stumped as to how to solve for $[\alpha,μ_x,μ_z,σ_{xx},σ_{zz},σ_{xz}]$ in terms of $[b_0,b_1,b_2,b_3,b_4,b_5]$. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: You could include the original problem in full in your post to see if someone can help you out.

Comment: Sadly, this is an original problem. I've defined a model according to the first formula but the second formula has much more interpretable coefficients.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope that helps:
\begin{equation}
    p(x,y) =
      \frac{1}{2 \pi  \sigma_X \sigma_Y \sqrt{1-\rho^2}}
      \exp\left(
        -\frac{1}{2(1-\rho^2)}\left[
          \frac{(x-\mu_X)^2}{\sigma_X^2} +
          \frac{(y-\mu_Y)^2}{\sigma_Y^2} -
          \frac{2\rho(x-\mu_X)(y-\mu_Y)}{\sigma_X \sigma_Y}
      \right]\right)
\end{equation}
We would like to get all the parameters from the coefficents of the polynomial
\begin{equation}
 p(x,y) \propto \exp-\left(ax^{2}+by^{2}+cxy+dx+ey+f\right)
\end{equation}
This can be acomplished by comparing the polynomial terms
\begin{equation}
 \begin{aligned}
 \rho &= \frac{c}{2\sqrt{ab}}\\
 \sigma_{x} &=\sqrt{\frac{2b}{4ab-c^2}}\\
 \sigma_{y} &=\sqrt{\frac{2a}{4ab-c^2}}\\
 \rho \sigma_{x} \sigma_{y} &= \frac{c}{4ab-c^2}\\
 \mu_x &= \frac{2bd+ce}{4ab-c^2}\\
 \mu_y &= \frac{2ae+dc}{4ab-c^2}
 \end{aligned}
\end{equation}
From these expressions we can calculate the expectation value of $x^2$ and $xy$.
\begin{equation}
 \begin{aligned}
 \mathbb{E}(x^2) &= \sigma_{x}^2 + \mu_{x}^2\\
 \mathbb{E}(xy) &= \rho \sigma_{x} \sigma_{y} + \mu_{x}\mu_{y}
 \end{aligned}
\end{equation}
hope I did not make any algebra errors